# DXA Content Delivery database version

Tags: dxa

Is there any difference between DXA 1.0 and 1.1 in the Content Delivery Database?

Think of

- difference in the data published by the DD4T TBBs (or do DXA 1.0 and DXA 1.1 use the same DD4T version?)
- information published by DXA 1.1 which is not published DXA 1.0 or vice versa
- DXA version information in the published data

Content Manager side, DXA modules and any content delivery libraries or code are not in scope of this question,

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Some things that immediately spring to mind are:

1. DXA 1.1 uses a JSON DD4T format for published content (instead of XML)
2. DXA 1.1 has some changes in the way configuration is managed (in 1.0 you could have global and local configuration for a multi-locale/publication site, but in 1.1 all configuration is local to the context publication)

See the [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v2/GUID-63A40EF1-7619-4CC8-9A80-D9766FC3B6B2) for more on these.

Answer (score 2):

What Will Price mentions is all true, but I would say, mainly because there is a difference between DXA 1.0 and 1.1 on the CM side (new TBBs, Schema changes etc.), there will also be a difference in what is published to the CD side of course.

The SDL Tridion Reference Implementation (DXA 1.0) uses DD4T 1.31, and DXA 1.1 uses a custom DD4T build based on 1.31 publishing JSON rather than XML. The source of that custom build can be found in this fork on GitHub https://github.com/willprice76/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/tree/json_and_xml_serialization

Now the serialization changes above do not include publishing of additional data (note that DXA 1.0 did not have ECL support, and DXA 1.1 has, so you could see that as additional data which is published in case of an ECL item). That is something which will happen in the upcoming DXA 1.2 release by the way. DXA 1.2 will use DD4T 2.0 (or a custom build of DD4T 2.0 depending on whether our pull requests are accepted before DXA 1.2 is released) which includes additional data published for ECL items.

The only version information we publish is that of the HTML design, but that is separate from the DXA version anyways, so that could be different regardless of the DXA version.